# Geom_polygon does not fill with correct data

Tags: r, ggplot2, spatial-data-frame

I am trying to plot a zipcode map of the Netherlands and fill it, but my 'fill' is the same for every variable I try to fill it with, which is not correct. My code looks like this:

```
ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = long, y = lat)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill="variable1", group="zipcode"))
```

My dataframe is a SpatialPolygonsDataframe and the variables I tried to fill are either numerical or factors.

The code above gives me the following map, which looks the same, no matter which variable I place after `fill`

[image]

Comment: arguments in `aes` should not be in quotes or use `ggplot2::aes_string()`

Comment: I tried without the quotes and this gives me the errors "object variable X not found".

I think this has something to do with the way the SpatialPolygonsDataframe is shaped.

I can call the variable only by using df@data$variable, could this be the reason this argument does not recognize my variables?